In biblatex, how can I change a period in custom location+pages for incollection types?
I am using Overleaf to write a paper. With biblatex, I am trying to change the default setting of how @incollection types are reported in the bibliography, specifically, I want this:

Bedoussac L, Journet E, Hauggaard-Nielsen H, Naudin C, Corre-Hellou G,
Prieur L, Jensen E and Justes E (2014) Eco-functional Intensification
by Cereal-Grain Legume Intercropping in Organic Farming Systems for
Increased Yields, Reduced Weeds and Improved Grain Protein
Concentration. In: Organic Farming, Prototype for Sustainable
Agricultures. Springer, Dordrecht, pp. 47-63.

I added some preamble code to change it to this:

Bedoussac L, Journet E, Hauggaard-Nielsen H, Naudin C, Corre-Hellou G,
Prieur L, Jensen E and Justes E (2014) Eco-functional Intensification
by Cereal-Grain Legume Intercropping in Organic Farming Systems for
Increased Yields, Reduced Weeds and Improved Grain Protein
Concentration. In: Organic Farming, Prototype for Sustainable
Agricultures. Springer, Dordrecht.pp. 47-63.

But I can't get the period after the location (Dordrecht) to change into a comma and space. I got it to work by changing the location to "Dordrecht, pp. 47-63", but I want a clean method to do this properly. Any help is appreciated. This is what I got so far to get the above:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,
        natbib=true,
        uniquename=false,
        maxcitenames=2,
        maxbibnames=99,
        giveninits=true,
        doi=true,
        isbn=false,
        url=false,
        eprint=false
        ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

% Redefine publisher+location+date macro for inbook and incollection entries
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}[1]{%
  \printlist{#1}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\publocdelim\addcomma\addspace}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \newunit}

% Add "In:" before book title for @incollection references
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
   \ifentrytype{incollection}{%
    \printtext{In:}\addspace
  }{}}

% Customize the pages format for inbook references: add pp. and show full range
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{pages}{pp. \thefield{pages}}

% Remove editor and chapter for incollection references
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{chapter}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{doi}{}

\begin{document}

\cite{Bedoussac2014}

\printbibliography

\end{document}

This is in my sample.bib file:
@incollection{Bedoussac2014,
  author    = {Bedoussac, L. and Journet, E. and Hauggaard-Nielsen, H. and Naudin, C. and Corre-Hellou, G. and Prieur, L. and Jensen, E. and Justes, E.},
  booktitle = {Organic Farming, Prototype for Sustainable Agricultures},
  title     = {Eco-functional Intensification by Cereal-Grain Legume Intercropping in Organic Farming Systems for Increased Yields, Reduced Weeds and Improved Grain Protein Concentration},
  chapter   = {3},
  doi       = {10.1007/978-94-007-7927-3},
  isbn      = {978-94-007-7926-6},
  pages     = {47-63},
  publisher = {Springer},
  address   = {Dordrecht},
  type      = {Book Section},
  year      = {2014}
}


Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Thanks, added a complete working example.

There would be \bibpagespunct command, but it’s already defined according to your preferences. The problem is in these commands from your MWE:
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{chapter}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{doi}{}

They don’t work.
Firstly, to hide the doi field and to do it only for incollection entries, you should use instead:
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions[incollection]{doi=false}

Secondly and most importantly: remove \DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{chapter}{} and customise the chapter+pages bibmacro.
\renewbibmacro*{chapter+pages}{%
    \ifentrytype{incollection}%
        {}%
        {\printfield{chapter}}%
    \setunit{\bibpagespunct}
    \printfield{eid}%
    \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
    \printfield{pages}%
    \newunit}

Finally, you might not to customise the pages field format. I think you’d like to hold the low capital letter in the string, but it depends on the punctuation. If the code works as you are looking for, regarding the punctuation, you don’t need even more to customise the pages field format.
Then, I am tooking the liberty to give you two feedback on your MWE.
I don’t like your customisation of the in: bibmacro. Prefere the next one.
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
    \ifentrytype{incollection}%
        {\bibstring{in}%
            \printunit{\intitlepunct}}%
        {}}

I don’t understand your publisher+location+date new bibmacro, even the punctuation. I suggest to restore a conventional code.
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
    \printlist{publisher}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printlist{location}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \usebibmacro{date}%
    \newunit}

I give you back the MWE.
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @incollection{Bedoussac2014,
    author    = {Bedoussac, L. and Journet, E. and Hauggaard-Nielsen, H. and Naudin, C. and Corre-Hellou, G. and Prieur, L. and Jensen, E. and Justes, E.},
    booktitle = {Organic Farming, Prototype for Sustainable Agricultures},
    title     = {Eco-functional Intensification by Cereal-Grain Legume Intercropping in Organic Farming Systems for Increased Yields, Reduced Weeds and Improved Grain Protein Concentration},
    chapter   = {3},
    doi       = {10.1007/978-94-007-7927-3},
    isbn      = {978-94-007-7926-6},
    pages     = {47-63},
    publisher = {Springer},
    address   = {Dordrecht},
    type      = {Book Section},
    year      = {2014}}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,
        natbib=true,
        uniquename=false,
        maxcitenames=2,
        maxbibnames=99,
        giveninits=true,
        doi=true,
        isbn=false,
        url=false,
        eprint=false
        ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
    \printlist{publisher}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printlist{location}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \usebibmacro{date}%
    \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
    \ifentrytype{incollection}%
        {\bibstring{in}%
            \printunit{\intitlepunct}}%
        {}}

\renewbibmacro*{chapter+pages}{%
    \ifentrytype{incollection}%
        {}%
        {\printfield{chapter}}%
    \setunit{\bibpagespunct}
    \printfield{eid}%
    \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
    \printfield{pages}%
    \newunit}

    
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions[incollection]{doi=false}

\begin{document}

\cite{Bedoussac2014}

\printbibliography

\end{document}


Thanks, this worked! Also thanks for the additional tips.
